# Remove sub-string from WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have a stored procedure that is using the [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   ColumnBB,
   ColumnCC
FROM TableAA WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE SUBSTRING(ColumnAA, 1, 17) = @VariableA;
```

How can I prevent an index scan for this query and make it execute quickly?

Comment: Do you have an index on `ColumnAA`? Also, why do you have a `WITH (NOLOCK)` in there?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid (=prevent) an index scan?

Comment: Garry, did any of the answers here solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

If you can't modify the schema per [db2's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15104/2660), then try:

```
WHERE 
       ColumnAA LIKE @VariableA + '%' 
   AND LEN(@VariableA) >= 17          -- safety check
```

Note that if `@VariableA` is shorter than 17 characters, then you may match unwanted strings using just a `LIKE`.  For example, `'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'` is `LIKE` `'The%'`, but that doesn't satisfy the requirements of your original `SUBSTRING` query.

Aaron also brings up a good point that the `DISTINCT` may be the ultimate culprit.  Why do you have it in there?  Is it something that should be replaced with an appropriate unique index?

Answer (score 4):

Are the substring ranges always the same? If so, you could turn that into a computed column, and index it.

Comment: The substring value is always the same.  I cannot make any index or column changes to the DB.  I need to be able to handle in the TSQL.

Answer (score 4):

Replace it with `like` and see how it goes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   ColumnBB,
   ColumnCC
FROM TableAA (NOLOCK)
WHERE ColumnAA like @VariableA + '%'
```

`like` is faster than `substring` in this case ([proof](http://sqlserverperformance.idera.com/tsql-optimization/replace-poorly-performing-substring-function-sql-server-statement/)).

The newer predicate is not semantically the same as the old one, but as far as your requirements go the results should be as expected given you provide correct `@VariableA` values.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64598/discussion-on-answer-by-denis-valeev-remove-sub-string-from-where-clause).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the scan is caused by the `DISTINCT` (and the resulting sort). Does it go away without the `DISTINCT`? Wonder if you can fool the optimizer into dealing with that separately, e.g.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  -- the suggestion I gave you on twitter:
  SELECT ColumnBB, ColumnCC
  FROM dbo.TableAA
  WHERE ColumnAA LIKE @VariableA + '%'
)
SELECT ColumnBB, ColumnCC 
FROM x
GROUP BY ColumnBB, ColumnCC;
```

I think the optimizer will see through this and won't necessarily short-circuit, but it could be worth a try.

If you want to improve performance, your best bet is to be open to schema changes. E.g. the clustered index scan may also be prevented if you add ColumnCC as an `INCLUDE` column to the index on `ColumnBB`. That will almost certainly help this query, but it may or may not be better for other queries.

Comment: You mean add both CC and BB as includes to the index on AA, right? Or, if the `DISTINCT` is necessary, add CC and BB as part of the key to the index on AA.

Comment: Yep, sorry. Would have kept better track with real column names I suspect.